# How to Get parent page information and from an Iframe and using the information to show a PHP page in the Iframe

Tags: php, javascript, widget

I am creating widget with PHP. The widget will be a Iframe widget. Which will take the title of the parent page and pass the title to a PHP page which will be seen with the result in the Iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> . Which will take the title of the parent page and pass the title to a PHP page which will be seen with the result in the Iframe.

This is going to be difficult if not impossible. If your widget runs on a different domain than the embedding page, you will not be able to access the parent page's `title` property due to the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Answer (score 1):

If you're on the same domain you should be able to use `window.parent.document.title`. If you're not on the same domain but have control of the parent you could pass the title in via a query string argument.

Comment: Upvoted for clearest response. see Pekka's answer for a link about the Same Origin Policy to understand why iframes act this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you're parent and child (the iframed) pages are on the same domain, you can use something like:

```
parent.document.getElementById('id_of_element').whatever();
```

to access the parent window's data.